# CSS: position nested element slightly outside of parent element's bounds

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have 2 divs, one nested inside of the other.  According to the page design, the nested div needs to appear to be "on top of" the parent div, as in:
[image: this image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0m1a1Z0Q19212e2y0o1m/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-18%20at%204.54.06%20PM.png?v=cea05db2))</sub>

I've got the CSS coded for both elements, using a negative top margin on the nested div to attempt to simulate the desired effect.  However, instead of appearing outside of the parent's bounds, the nested div's top 10px or so are getting cut off, as in:
[image: this image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0u332c091m2j070g461f/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-18%20at%204.54.18%20PM.png?v=911f961f))</sub>

I don't want to position the element absolutely, because a goal for this page is that it be responsive.

HTML for divs:

```
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="child-div">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for the divs:

```
.container-div {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: -15px 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You don't need to apply `position:absolute` to the nested `div`.

And `margin` probably wouldn't be the best practice in this case.

Just add `position:relative` to the nested `div`, and set it's `top` to any number you want. In your case, it would probably be negative.

Check out [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Kaw/2/)

Answer (score 17):

`overflow: hidden` on the parent would have done it perfectly !