# How to move the image partially outside of MUI dialog?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

Trying to move an image outside of [MUI dialog](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/), so that the bottom part of the image will be inside dialog while the upper part of the image will be outside the dialog. I've tried to implement this solution [CSS: position nested element slightly outside of parent element's bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409067/css-position-nested-element-slightly-outside-of-parent-elements-bounds) but it doesn't work.

This is my dialog:

```
<Dialog open={this.state.open} onEnter={console.log("Hey.")}>
   <div className="dialog-logo-outside" />
   <DialogTitle>Hello CodeSandbox</DialogTitle>
   <DialogContent>Start editing to see some magic happen!</DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

This is CSS:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.dialog-logo-outside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  top: -50px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/24p8XE7.jpg);
}
```

Here you can see example in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dialog-sample-forked-8w5wt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I needed to add `overflow: inherit` to the paper subcomponent of Dialog, you can see a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dialog-sample-forked-3ru7k

More about `overflow` CSS property you can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

> The overflow CSS shorthand property sets the desired behavior for an
> element's overflow — i.e. when an element's content is too big to fit
> in its block formatting context — in both directions.

```js
<Dialog
          classes={{
            paper: "dialog-paper"
          }}
          open={this.state.open}
          onEnter={console.log("Hey.")}
        >
          <div className="dialog-logo-outside" />
          <DialogTitle>Hello CodeSandbox</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>Start editing to see some magic happen!</DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
```

```css
.dialog-paper {
  overflow: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: Demo does not work. Another class forces this property to have another value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me, I've fixed the example.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update the link in the answer. I still see the cropped image. And will be better to add your code direct in the answer as a snippet.